# Change project to Web Application in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008

in a VS 2008 solution I just inherited there is a normal class library project that actually should be a web application project (because it is a web service indeed). What is the best way to convert it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also found out that this can be done manually by adding:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

to the project file (*.proj) just under `<ProjectGuid>...</ProjectGuid>`

Answer (score 5):

Create a new Web Service (or Web Application) project and add the class library files to it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to do this.

There's plenty of info out there on using class library projects for web applications - [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668164.aspx) for one example.